# Using openni kinect depth camera in Gazebo Garden

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-plugin, depth-image

I am trying to get more customization lever into my depth camera in Gazebo Garden. So far I am just using the default depth_camera sensor tag but there I have some alignment issues as described [here](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/105347/gazebo-camera-and-depth-camera-with-same-parameters-show-different-fovs)

After some googling I found out about the openni kinect depth camera plugin. I understand that this is for gazebo classic but does anyone know if it can be used with gazebo garden as well?

I installed the gazebo_ros_pkgs successfully as described [here](https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_installing&cat=connect_ros). Is it possible to use the opennni kinect plugin in my gazebo garden model.sdf file? If so could anyone explain how?

Thanks a lot in advance!